# Derived column in a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

The journey builder thats been used has entry event as DE populated with data imported from Automation studio

Can I create a Data extension column with values derived from two other columns in same data extension calculated on the fly once the import from the automation studio is completed?

Example

```
Amount |  Rate | Days | Final Amount ((Amount+ Amount*rate*Days))/Days
30000  |  0.25 |    5 | calculated value
40000  |  0.85 |   15 | calculated value
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  In your Automation -- instead of importing directly to the final entry data extension, just import into a temporary staging data extension and use a Query Activity to add the rows and calculated values to the entry data extension.

If you don't need this calculated value for a decision split, then you could just calculate the Final Amount with AMPscript in the email.  This option wouldn't require any changes to the automation.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. Have your Automation populate a Temp DE and then write a SQL to populate your Journey DE along with the derived column.

Or else, have another DE (DE2) which has a derived field and can join with your journey DE. Link these DEs in the Contact builder and then refer that in the journey